# Fill Date field in a hook form alter with ajax callback

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm trying to populate some fields via Ajax.

Is working good with textfields, but no with date field and select list.

After the rebuild of the form the date field is empty and the select too.

Here my code:

```
function PORTO_SUB_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{ if ($form_id == 'datore_node_form')
{
global $user;
  $form['title']['#type'] = 'hidden';
  $form['title']['#value'] = 'test';

  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="datore_node_form_prefix">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['user_copy'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => 'Sono io il datore!',
      '#ajax' => array(
        'event'=>'click',
        'callback' =>'user_copy_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'datore_node_form_prefix',
    ),
  );
  // field_group_hide_field_groups($form, array('group_azienda'));

  $user = user_load($user->uid);

  dpm($form);

  if (!empty($form_state['values']['field_cognome']))
  {
    unset($form_state['input']['field_cognome']['und'][0]['value']);
    $form['field_cognome']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = $user->field_cognome['und'][0]['value'];
    $form['field_nome']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = $user->field_nome['und'][0]['value'];
    $form['field_luogo_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['value']['#value'] = $user->field_luogo_di_nascita1['und'][0]['value'];

    $form['field_data_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['#date_items']['#value'] = $user->field_data_di_nascita1['und'][0]['value'];
    $form['field_data_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['#date_items']['value']['#value'] = $user->field_data_di_nascita1['und'][0]['value'];
    $form['field_data_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['#date_items']['value'] = $user->field_data_di_nascita1['und'][0]['value'];
    $form['field_data_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['#default_value']['#value'] = $user->field_data_di_nascita1['und'][0]['value'];
    $form['field_data_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['#default_value']['value']['#value'] = $user->field_data_di_nascita1['und'][0]['value'];
    $form['field_data_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = $user->field_data_di_nascita1['und'][0]['value'];
return $form;
}

function user_copy_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state)
{
dpm($form['field_data_di_nascita1']['und'][0]['#default_value']['value']);
return $form;
}
```

Comment: Try to debug your forms array and check if you store the values at the right place.

Comment: I found the #default_value filled with the value but in the UI date field is not populated, Why is so hard to do such a basic thing?

Comment: In the debug both `#default_value` and `#date_items` are filled with the value but after the rebuild the date input field is empty, Why is so hard to do such a basic thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution finally:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1984838#comment-11736060

I had to fill both $form and $form_state values...

$form_state['input']['your_field_to_change']['und'][0]['value'] = $new_date;
$form['fyour_field_to_change']['und'][0]['#default_value']['value'] = $new_date;